# Include and filter sub collections in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to build a base level `GetAll()` method in my repository that will ensure all the data is available, and correct, for other methods in my repo.

Its fairly complicated due to existing DB design, but it revolves around including collections that dictate whether a `group` or `driver` can be seen by the current credential.

Unfortunately its throwing an error at the moment:

> The include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type

Here is the code

```
return groups
    .Include(g => g.GroupDriverDicts)
    .Include(g => g.GroupDriverDicts.Select(d => d.Driver))
    .Include(g => g.GroupDriverDicts
                   .Select(d => d.Driver
                                 .DriverCredentialDicts
                                 .Select(dcd => dcd.CredentialId == this.AccountId)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot filter included data like this. You have to load all *DriverCredentialDicts*. You can try something like:

```
return groups
    .Include(g => g.GroupDriverDicts.Select(d => d.Driver.DriverCredentialDicts))
    .Where(g => g.GroupDriverDicts.Any(gdd => gdd.Driver.DriverCredentialDicts
            .Any(dcd => dcd.CredentialId == this.AccountId)));
```

It will give you *all* groups where, *any of DriverCredentialDicts* has id which is equal to `this.AccountId`.